# Audio Devices menu not appearing for agents in the CCP - Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-connect

**Only security profile that allows audio device settings appears to be Admin. Agents need the ability to change the ringer setting.** How to enable audio device settings option for other users/agents working i have referred in multiple docs, but there is no straight answer for it, however the below link suggest to create custom CCP, if that's case, can anyone show steps if we can create a Custom CCP in amazon connect.

Link: https://repost.aws/questions/QUZuQ-KQz4Sve1xnWaaDJQmA/audio-devices-menu-not-appearing-for-agents-in-the-ccp-amazon-connect